# Не удается создать стек в теле класса

Tags: c++, классы, стек

Хочу создать стек с элементами класса Disk в классе Pole, но получаю ошибку: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "<"

Pole.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stack>
#include "Disk.h"


class Pole
{
private:
    char num;

    stack <Disk> pole; //здесь ошибка

public:
    Pole();

    ~Pole();

    void Number(int n);

    int Get_Number();

};
```

Comment: в каком месте? Между stack и <Disk>?

Comment: Как компилируете? в c++98?

Comment: удаление пробела ни к чему не приводит.

Comment: А добавление `std::` к stack?

Comment: Добавление std:: к stack помогло, спасибо.

Comment: @vp_arth Вы бы оформили как ответ, а то чуть было не написал свой :-)

Comment: @Harry, допишите свой. Это "вопрос-опечатка" же..

Comment: @vp_arth Ни за что :) - ответ уже дан, и ответ полный. И, кстати, вопрос вызван *не* опечаткой. Опечаткой - это если бы автор написал `steck <Disk> pole;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stack` у вас указывает на ::stack.
Не знаю, где конкретно он у вас определён, но похоже, что определён, и не имеет шаблонной формы(иначе была бы другая ошибка).

Варианты решения:

- Указать namespace: `std::stack<Disk>`
- Импортировать namespace полностью: `using namespace std;`
- Импортировать из namespace нужный символ: `using std::stack;`